# How to Fix a Corrupted USB Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, virus, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

I recently just wanted to move all my data from old laptop to a new one using a USB. The total data was around 10GB and my USB has 16GB space. It took me around 1-2 hours to move the old data to new ones. So far there was no problem moving the data. But a while after it finished moving the data, the USB shows unrecognizable words/letters in my file manager. I cannot access any data inside as the syntax is unrecognizable. Is my USB suddenly corrupted? Is there any ways to fix it? Attached is a screenshot of my USB in file manager.

[File corruption screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a92Xb.jpg)

Comment: I assume you performed cut and paste operations instead of copying and pasting the files thus you only have a single copy of the now corrupt files?

Comment: yes you are very correct. Could cut and paste be the source of the problem?

Comment: No; Bad hardware is likely the real cause. 2 hours to move 16 GB indicates there was a problem with the initial transfer. That’s extremely slow even for a USB 2.0 device

Comment: format your USB drive in NTFS format and then try copy/paste

Comment: Do you know possible ways to solve and safe my corrupted files?@Ramhound

Comment: If you are moving data from one pc to another, why are you not doing it over the network, rather than using a USB drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not even looking at actual files, you're looking at complete garbage data written all over the FAT directory some of which just happens to be recognized as a file.

This doesn't look very recoverable. I really suspect that if this happened to the root directory, then you're very likely to have the same kind of garbage in the FAT (which describes *where* the files are supposed to be), and probably in the actual files themselves. (Either the flash memory has gone bad, or something with the USB connection went wrong, or something like that.)

I think you'll have a much better chance recovering the files *from the old laptop* (where they were merely deleted) than from the USB stick.